# Bayesian update on two possibilities when test is unreliable

Tags: bayesian

Imagine I have an integer variable `A` that can be `1` or `2`. And I have a test that returns the value of `A`, but this test fails (returns wrong value) with probability $\beta$.

I start out with a uniform prior: $P(A=1) = 0.5, P(A=2) = 0.5 $.

I perform a single test, and it returns `A=1`. According to standard Bayes formula I can update my beliefs as follows:

$$
P(B|A=1) = (1-\beta)
\\
P(B|A=2) = \beta
\\
P(A=1) = \frac{P(B|A=1)P(A=1)}{P(B)} = \frac{(1-\beta)0.5}{0.5} = 1-\beta
\\
P(A=2) = \frac{P(B|A=2)P(A=2)}{P(B)} = \frac{\beta0.5}{0.5} = \beta
$$

If I plug in some value for $\beta$, for example 20%, then I get $P(A=1) = 0.8, P(A=2) = 0.2$. And that makes sense - if I performed a single test with 20% failure rate I would be about 80% sure in the outcome.

But now imagine I perform three tests in a row (starting with the same uniform prior), and they return `A=1`,`A=2`, `A=1`. I calculated the update:
$$
P(B|A=1) = (1-\beta)\beta(1-\beta)
\\
P(B|A=2) = \beta(1-\beta)\beta
\\
P(A=1) = \frac{P(B|A=1)P(A=1)}{P(B)}
       = \frac{P(B|A=1)P(A=1)}{avg(P(B|A=1),P(B|A=2))}
       = \frac{(1-\beta)\beta(1-\beta)0.5}{((1-\beta)\beta(1-\beta) + \beta(1-\beta)\beta)0.5}
       = \frac{(1-\beta)^2\beta}{(1-\beta)\beta(1 - \beta + \beta)} = 1-\beta
\\
P(A=2) = \frac{P(B|A=2)P(A=2)}{P(B)}
       = \frac{P(B|A=2)P(A=2)}{avg(P(B|A=1),P(B|A=2))}
       = \frac{\beta(1-\beta)\beta0.5}{((1-\beta)\beta(1-\beta) + \beta(1-\beta)\beta)0.5}
       = \frac{(1-\beta)\beta^2}{(1-\beta)\beta(1 - \beta + \beta)} = \beta
$$

I get the same result! And I will get the same result even if I have 1001 tests for `A=1` and 1000 for `A=2` - these calculations show that  I should still trust the `A=1` with 80% ($1-\beta$) confidence, even though I had mostly the same number of evidence both ways.

This seems incorrect. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your analysis result is correct. To illustrate, let's see what happens if a '1' and a '2' are returned. In such case, the conditional probability that

P(a '1' and a '2' are returned | the true integer is 1) = 0.8 * 0.2 = 0.16

which equals

P(a '1' and a '2' are returned | the true integer is 2) = 0.2 * 0.8 = 0.16.

Since P(A=1) = P(A=2) = 0.5, when applying Bayesian, we see that the conditional probability

P(the true integer is 1 | a '1' and a '2' are returned) = 0.16/(0.16+0.16) = 0.5,

which is the same as the initial probability P(A=1) = P(A=2) = 0.5. This indicates that a pair of returned '1' and '2' does not provide any extra information about whether the true value is 1 or 2. In other words, the information provided by a returned '1' and '2' cancels each other.

Thus, when you receive N returned '2' and (N+1) returned '1', the information provided by the N pairs of '1' and '2' cancels each other, and only the information provided by a single '1' is useful. Thus, the final probability is same as a single '1' is returned, as long as the model is symmetric, that is,
P('1' is returned | true integer is 1) = P('2' is returned | true integer is 2).